# Set HTML input form width to 100%

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML form that previously I had the width of the input fields to be 100% but I made some changes and did not know what caused the change.

```
    <form action="/forms.php" method="post">
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="fullname" placeholder="Name" width:100%>
    </div>
    <div>
        <textarea id="msg" name="message" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="emailaddress" placeholder="Email Address">
        <input type="text" name="contactno" placeholder="Contact Number">
    </div>
        <input type="submit" name="send" value="Submit" id="subsubmit" class="btn2"/>
    </form>
```

I have already added the following CSS in my HTML

```
.input {
width: 100%;
}

.textarea {
width: 100%;
}

.form {
width: 100%;
}
```

Fiddle link - https://jsfiddle.net/v83g4003/

Comment: Try to add in CSS display:block

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`input` `textarea` `form` are HTML tags not a class. You have used `.` in css before HTML tags which indicates it as a class thats why your css is not working.

Just remove `.` in your css

***Stack Snippet***

```css
input {
  width: 100%;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
}

form {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form action="/forms.php" method="post">
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="fullname" placeholder="Name" width:100%>
  </div>
  <div>
    <textarea id="msg" name="message" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="emailaddress" placeholder="Email Address">
    <input type="text" name="contactno" placeholder="Contact Number">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="send" value="Submit" id="subsubmit" class="btn2" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks. That fixed it. Turns out that I accidentally added a dot by mistake

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this edited jsfiddle: [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/zpvdhujc/1/)

Also using `width:100%` as a html attribute will not work, in html you will need to do it like 'width="100%"'. Though using a CSS is better since it seperates your design from your logic (as you probably already knew)